# Spring Security OAuth + Spring Session

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-session

I'm using Spring Security OAuth to build application with token based authentication (using this article http://porterhead.blogspot.com/2014/05/securing-rest-services-with-spring.html).

In the next step I want to store some additional data with token. I decided, that Spring Session is good enough for it. First, it have `HeaderHttpSessionStrategy` (user sends session ID in custom header - `X-Auth-Token`), second, it supports different storages (including Redis - good for quick access to session data).

Spring Security OAuth uses `Bearer Authorization`, that means I need to create child class from `HeaderHttpSessionStrategy`, which will return correct session ID (not from `X-Auth-Token`).

So my questions are:

1. How to hook on login success method in Spring Security OAuth and create session with provided ID (ID == new generated token) in this moment?
2. How to hook on logout method?
3. Is it right way to use Spring Session in this case? If not, what alternatives?

Comment: one of the purpose of using OAuth is to make the rest service stateless, if you want to add additional data in your token consider using `TokenEnhancer`